# How to fetch from file using if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

I want to make this if-statement because it is only fetching **b** from bilalkhan. And the second one I don't know how to fetch. Just the like the third one and so on. How to fetch these?

**Here is file.txt**

```
bilalkhan 02/02/1995 709734234 243322223 address current 2019 324324
```

**Here is code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    FILE * fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
    char one='1', two='2', three='3', four='4', five='5', six='6', seven='7', eight='8';
    int buffer, option;
    printf("%c. Your Name: \n",one);
    printf("%c. Your Date of Birth: \n",two);
    printf("%c. Your ID Card Number: \n",three);
    printf("%c. Your Phone Number: \n",four);
    printf("%c. Your Address: \n",five);
    printf("%c. Your Account: \n",six);
    printf("%c. Your Fixing Year: \n",seven);
    printf("%c. Your Amount: \n",eight);

    printf("Select your choice to update: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    while((buffer = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
      if (option == 1){
        printf("Your name: %c",buffer);
        break;
      }
      else if(option == 2){
        printf("Your DOB: %c", buffer);
        break;
      }
      else{
        printf("Select right option");
        break;
      }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: A combination of `fgets()` and `strtok()` in a while loop will be a little easier to code than using `fgetc()` with `if()` statements.  Is `if()` a requirement here, or can other constructs be considered?

Comment: *it is only fetching b from bilalkhan. And the second one I don't know how to fetch* of course, because of your `break` stopping the loop `while`. if you remove it you will have the unreadable message `Your name: bYour name: iYour name: lYour name: aYour name: lYour name: kYour name: hYour name: aYour name: nYour name: <newline` do you really want that ? Note also even you choose option 2 you will read name rather than date of birthday

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to fetch the second one. I used break to stop the repetation of loop but it only gave me one alphabet

Comment: there are several ways to do, as said by the first remark you can read all the line then extract the field you want. Anyway there is something strange, how to distinguish the address from the other fields ? I mean is the address  only one word or several separated by space ?

Comment: Don't you see the file.txt bruno that it is seperated by spaces

Comment: @natashaBibi yes I see but I just remark I *never* see an address on only one word, for instance mine is on 5 words

Comment: @natashaBibi look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

> it is only fetching b from bilalkhan

this is because of the `break` stopping your loop `while`

It seems each field is on only one word, including the address, in that case a simple use of `fscanf` solves your problem, for instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 256

int main()
{
  FILE * fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
  int option, rank;
  char word[MAX_LEN];
  static const char * const msg[] = {
    "Name",
    "Date of Birth",
    "ID Card Number",
    "Phone Number",
    "Address",
    "Account",
    "Fixing Year",
    "Amount"
  };

  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("cannot read file.txt");
    return -1;
  }

  for (option = 1; option <= sizeof(msg)/sizeof(char *); ++option)
    printf("%d. Your %s:\n", option, msg[option-1]);

  fputs("Select your choice to update: ", stdout);

  if ((scanf("%d", &option) != 1) ||
      (option < 1) || (option > sizeof(msg)/sizeof(char *))) {
    puts("invalid choice");
    fclose(fp);
    return -1;
  }

  /* the expected word is at rank option, other must be bypasses */
  for (rank = 0; rank != option; ++rank) {
    if (fscanf(fp, "%255s", word) != 1) {
      puts("invalid input file");
      fclose(fp);
      return -1;
    }
  }

  printf("Your %s: %s\n", msg[option - 1], word);

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
cannot read file.txt: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo "bilalkhan 02/02/1995 709734234 243322223 address current 2019 324324" > file.txt
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1. Your Name:
2. Your Date of Birth:
3. Your ID Card Number:
4. Your Phone Number:
5. Your Address:
6. Your Account:
7. Your Fixing Year:
8. Your Amount:
Select your choice to update: 0
invalid choice
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1. Your Name:
2. Your Date of Birth:
3. Your ID Card Number:
4. Your Phone Number:
5. Your Address:
6. Your Account:
7. Your Fixing Year:
8. Your Amount:
Select your choice to update: 9
invalid choice
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1. Your Name:
2. Your Date of Birth:
3. Your ID Card Number:
4. Your Phone Number:
5. Your Address:
6. Your Account:
7. Your Fixing Year:
8. Your Amount:
Select your choice to update: 1
Your Name: bilalkhan
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1. Your Name:
2. Your Date of Birth:
3. Your ID Card Number:
4. Your Phone Number:
5. Your Address:
6. Your Account:
7. Your Fixing Year:
8. Your Amount:
Select your choice to update: 2
Your Date of Birth: 02/02/1995
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1. Your Name:
2. Your Date of Birth:
3. Your ID Card Number:
4. Your Phone Number:
5. Your Address:
6. Your Account:
7. Your Fixing Year:
8. Your Amount:
Select your choice to update: 8
Your Amount: 324324
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```